# Error for my div class div table

Tags: css

```
    <div id="apDiv"><table width="100%" class="flat-table flat-table-1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:10px"><font color="#003300">NAME</font></th>
                                <th style="width:200px"><font color="#003300">LICENSE#</font></th>
    <th style="width:200px"><font color="#003300">PLATE#</font></th>
                                <th style="width:5px"><font color="#003300">OFFENSES</font></th>
                                <th style="width:150px"><font color="#003300">OFFICER</font></th>
                                <th style="width:150px"><font color="#003300">RANK</font></th>
    <th style="width:200px"><font color="#003300">VIOLATION</font></th>
                                 <th style="width:200px"><font color="#003300">CONFISCATED</font></th>
                                 <th style="width:200px"><font color="#003300">V.PLACE</font></th>
                              <th style="width:500px"><font color="#0000CC">LAST UPDATE</font></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>


         <?php
         date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
                        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db("dbposo",$conn);


            $violationz=mysql_query("select *,date_format(ttime,'%h:%i %p') as timed from tblviolator ORDER BY ddate DESC") or die(mysql_error());

                        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($violationz))
                            {
                                $license=$data['license'];
                                $link=str_replace(" ","-",$license);
                                $fname=$data['fname'];
                                $mname=$data['mname'];
                                $lname=$data['lname'];
                                $plateno=$data['plateno'];
                                $offenses=$data['offenses'];
                                $type=$data['type'];
                                $officer=$data['officer'];
                                $violation=$data['violation'];
                                $confiscated=$data['confiscated'];
                                $violationplace=$data['violationplace'];
                                $ddate=$data['ddate'];
                                $ttime=$data['ttime'];


                                print "
                                    <tr license='X$license'>
                                    <td width='10px'><center><font size='1'>$lname,$fname,$mname</center></td>
                                    <td width='200px'><center><a href='edit_publicviolation.php?n=$link'><font color='#00FF00'>$license</font></a></center></td>
                                    <td width='90px'><center>$plateno</center></td>
                                    <td width='50px'><center>$offenses</center></td>
                                    <td width='530px'><center>$officer</center></td>
                                    <td width='280px'><center>$type</center></td>
                                    <td width='280px'><center>$violation</center></td>
                                    <td width='280px'><center>$confiscated</center></td>
                                    <td width='280px'><center>$violationplace</center></td>
                                    <td width='200px'><center>$ddate $ttime</center></td></tr>
                                    ";
                            }

                                    ?>  
    </table>

this is my CSS

<style type="text/css">
#apDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:1313px;
    height:233px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 35px;
    top: 299px;
}
 .flat-table {

        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
        border: none;
                border-radius: 3px;
               -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
               -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .flat-table th, .flat-table td {
        box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
            inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }
    .flat-table th {

        font-weight: normal;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        padding: 1em;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    .flat-table td {
        color: #f7f7f7;
        padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1.15em;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .flat-table tr {
        -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
        transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    }
    .flat-table-1 {
        background: green;
    }
    .flat-table-1 tr:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }
    .flat-table-2 tr:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    .flat-table-2 {
        background: #f06060;
    }
    .flat-table-3 {
        background: #52be7f;
    }
    .flat-table-3 tr:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

</style>
```

how can i make the div, inserted in my css?

because it blocks the screen but the original is still there, nothing happens.

every insert of record it blocks the screen, how can i fix it with my css?

please help.

here is the link of the image http://waaaaaas.weebly.com/

Comment: Not able to imagine your issue.

Comment: Not even sure what it is you're asking, can you try to explain a little better?

Comment: i can't upload images xD

Comment: http://waaaaaas.weebly.com/ this is what im talking about

Comment: This still isn't clear. What do you mean by "blocks the screen"? Also, what "original" is still there - original what? You haven't tried to remove-and-replace anything, or change anything, so I have no idea what "original" you're expecting to have disappeared.

Comment: i want that my table be part of my css. but i just downloaded my template and can't put table css xD

Comment: i want to put it in the middle, and even if i add record it must not block my footer

Comment: Remove `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#apDiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:1313px;
    height:233px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 35px;
    top: 299px;
}
```

Your div (which contains the table) is 'floating' above the page (overlapping your footer) because you've told it to. That's what setting position:absolute does - it takes the element in question out of the normal flow of the page, and positions it independently. Most of the CSS in the section above is unnecessary if you don't want it to do this. Instead, try simply:

```
#apDiv {
    width:1313px;
    height:233px;
}
```

See if that does what you want - it shouldn't overlap the footer any more at that point. You will almost certainly need to fiddle with this a bit more, but position:absolute is definitely not what you want.

Comment: how if i add more and more record, does it have scroll bar?

Comment: Because you've set the height of the table to 233px in your CSS - it's right there, staring you in the face! If your table has enough content that it can't all fit within the height you've set, you get scrollbars instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your div somewhere, otherwise your browser interprets the whole part below as a part of the div.